# Office (Outlook) AddIn and EXE file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, ms-office

I wrote an Outlook Plugin in Visual Studio 2012 and I need it to run an .exe file.

The problem is: When I add the .exe to my project it puts it in the bin\debug or bin\release folders.
But, the Plugin runs from the Office folder, so it has no connection to my .exe file.

How this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addin runs from the Office folder? Are you sure that is where it gets installed? Or is it because your are retrieving the location of the host app (which would be outlook.exe)? To retrieve the location of your addin, use something like the following:

```
//use CodeBase instead of Location because of Shadow Copy.
string codebase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
var vUri = new UriBuilder(codebase);
string vPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(vUri.Path + vUri.Fragment);
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(vPath);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vUri.Host)) directory = @"\\" + vUri.Host + directory;
```

Comment: You totally right! I checked the currentDirectory... Thanks!!